# jcreator - making a matching game

Tags: java, jcreator

I'm doing a Matching/Memory Game in JCreator using buttons and if-else statements

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TRsaO.jpg]

When you click the buttons, the image clicked will pop up then if you click the next one, but it's not the same image, then both will close. If you get the correct matching image, they both disable. My problem is the logic of matching it.

What will I do or use to make my program know that two buttons match?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html). Use that link to find out how to detect whether buttons are being pushed and what to do when pushed. To make an image appear, use an icon with the button. When you click, a number changes to a value. If you click another and a number is the same value, then they become disabled. If they are diffrent, then the icon is changed and the number reverts to zero. To disable, use button.setEnable(false);

Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) link for help with button icons/general button help.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do, although it takes more time, is giving each button a numeric value and use RandNum to decide them.  If you set it as a constant variable then you can use that to match them